# React renders my navigation alongside the body of my web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

On my web I have 4 possible status, anonymous, student and admin

and I should display different navigation bars depending your role, I think that my web should render that navigation bar when the user status change (a user log in log out) and should stay the same meanwhile.

the problem is my navigation bar is re-rendering every time I move to anothe site of the web

for example if I'm a logged in student and I move from / to /account, I'd see for like 0,5 seconds to 1 second the navigation bar I should see as  an anonymous account, and then it will change to a Student nav bar

this is the code I think is relevant to this problem

- to make the code more readable I'll post only like every logged in user is a student one, so I'd have two roles, logged in user or anonymous.

AuthUserContext.js

```
import React from 'react';

const AuthUserContext = React.createContext(null);

export default AuthUserContext;
```

withAuthentication.js

```
const withAuthentication = Component =>
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        authUser: null
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        authUser
          ? this.setState(() => ({ authUser }))
          : this.setState(() => ({ authUser: null }));
      });
    }

    render() {
      const { authUser } = this.state;

      return (
        <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authUser}>
          <Component />
        </AuthUserContext.Provider>
      );
    }
  };

export default withAuthentication;
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          <Route exact path={routes.LANDING} component={Home} />
          <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_UP} component={SignUp} />
          <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_IN} component={SignIn} />
          <Route exact path={routes.ACCOUNT} component={Account} />
          <Route
            exact
            path={routes.PASSWORD_FORGET}
            component={PasswordForget}
          />
          <Route exact path={routes.ALL_RULES} component={ListRules} />
          <Route
            path={routes.SPECIFIC_RULE}
            render={props => <RuleDescription {...props} />}
          />
          <Route exact path={routes.ALL_USERS} component={ListAllUsers} />
          <Route
            path={routes.USER_ACHIEVEMENTS}
            render={props => <ListAchievements {...props} />}
          />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuthentication(App);
```

Navigation.js

```
<AuthUserContext.Consumer>
  {authUser => 
     authUser
       ? <NavigationStudent authUser = {authUser}/>
       : <NavigationNonAuth />
  }
</AuthUserContext.Consumer>

const NavigationStudent= () =>
//normal nav bar
const NavigationNonAuth = () =>
//normal nav bar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a React-bootstrap problem, if someone has the same problem and use react-bootstrap here is the answer

[React is re rendering the navigation bar all time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51394466/react-is-re-rendering-the-navigation-bar-all-time)