# React is re rendering the navigation bar all time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First I thought this was a authentication problem, as I stated on another post a week ago, but now I tried to do a simple navigation bar without any complex code on it

```
class App extends Component {


render() {
return (
      <div>
      <Navigation/>
      <BrowserRouter/>
      <Route exact path= '/' component={Home}/>
      <Route exact path= '/Account' component={Account}/>
      <Route exact path= '/Users' component={Users}/>
      <BrowserRouter/>
      </div>

);
    }
}
```

export default App;

```
const Navigation = () =>

<NavigationNonAuth/>


const NavigationNonAuth = () =>

<Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
 <Navbar.Header>
  <Navbar.Brand>
    <a href='/'>Refactoring</a>
  </Navbar.Brand>
 <Navbar.Toggle />
</Navbar.Header>
<Navbar.Collapse>
 <Nav pullRight>
  <NavItem eventKey={1} href='/Account'>
    Account
  </NavItem>
  <NavItem eventKey={2} href='/Users'>
   Users
  </NavItem>
 </Nav>
 </Navbar.Collapse>
 </Navbar>
 export default Navigation;
```

Every time I click on any link of the navigator, /, /Account or /Users the navBar is rendering again and it shouldn't

I use on index.js this routing

```
ReactDOM.render((
<BrowserRouter>
<App />
</BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Why is the navigation bar rendering after every click on navigation href links?

Comment: Hi,
Probably look [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4463)

Comment: Seems the problem is React bootstrap, I still didn't manage to fix it, but I can confirm nav works without React bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the above there are a few issues, firstly you have used `<BrowserHistory/>` twice, this is an anti-pattern. You should only need to have the `<BrowserHistory/>` once at the top level of your application.

Secondly, `<BrowserHistory/>` is a HOC which is appending props to your `<App/>` component e.g. `history`, `location` & `match`. Because your `<App/>` is a `React.Component` and not a `React.PureComponent` every time one of these props changes your `<App />` is re-rendered rendering you `<Navigation/>` again.

The `history`, `location` & `match` will change when ever the route changes.

**The Solution**

1. Remove the lower `<BrowserHistory />` it is not needed
2. Change the `<App />` component to be a `React.PureComponent`
3. Pass the `history` prop to the the `<Navigation history={this.props.history}/>` component
4. Change your `<NavItem href='/Users' />` to be onClick events using history e.g. `<NavItem onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/Users')} />`

Finally read up on `React.PureComponent`

> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: I changed BrowserRouter to Switch on App.js and React.Component to React.PureComponent and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Is <NavItem /> a public component or something you have implemented your self? Is it using "history.push()"? Or is it just a normal <a> tab with href?

Comment: Just added 2 new steps to follow in my answer, React-Bootstrap is not aware of react-router and is currently just doing a standard navigation e.g. reloading the entire page. You have to programatically change the the route using history.push in your situation. (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)